# How is 'bolt-on' the same or different from add-on, extension, or module?

Tags: modules, semantics

I hear the term 'bolt-on' used in many contexts, specifically in my organization where PeopleSoft is used extensively.  I don't know exactly how it differs from an 'extension' of an existing product, a new module within an application, or an 'add-on' like you would purchase for a product you own.  Is there a more formal definition of 'bolt-on' that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: It is a fancy word for module, extension, etc.

Comment: "Bolt-on" is used to identify a component that is quickly and easily added to another system. This distinguishes it from components that require more sophisticated integration or customization.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those terms only have meaning in a specific context. In particular, I've only heard *bolt on* used with respect to PeopleSoft, where it means a separate application that integrates with the PeopleSoft ecosystem. Here's an article about [the difference between bolt-ons and customizations](http://www.cedarhillsgroup.com/knowledge-base/kbarticles/pros-and-cons-ofpeoplesoft-bolt-ons-versus-customizations) (tl/dr: a customization is a change to some part of the PeopleSoft system, a bolt-on is a separate thing that uses the PeopleSoft system).

The other terms you used, *module*, *extension*, and *add-on* also need to be considered in a particular context. For example, in some contexts a module could be some source code component that needs to be compiled into a program, while in others it may just be a functional component of the program that can be added without modifying the original.

If you're unsure of what someone in your office means by a particular term, ask them. If you feel you can't do that without looking uneducated, check the documentation for the pieces of software that they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Dudley stated in a comment below the answer, "bolt-on" is used to identify a component that is quickly and easily added to another system. This distinguishes it from components that require more sophisticated integration or customization.

[image]

I would also add that this is mainly a slang term, and can also mean anything added to a system hastily, without regard for suitability or esthetics.